# SSIS 2012 - Import flat file with embedded Backslash Double Quote

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm trying to import a flat file that's pipe delimited, with double quote text qualifier, but the file uses a backslash as an escape character for embedded double quotes. So a row for the company **Toys "R" Us** would come in like this-

```
accountno|companyname|address1
1234|"Toys \"R\" Us"|"123 Main St."
```

SQL 2012's import wizard recognizes a double-double quote as an embedded double quote, but it chokes on this backslash-double quote.  The data provider's response is "no one else has a problem with the format", so I'm wondering if this is just an option setting I've missed?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a simple `BULK INSERT` , Upload your data into a staging table first into sql server using BULK INSERT something like....

**Create Staging Table**

```
CREATE TABLE UploadFile_Staging
                       ( accountno   INT 
                       , companyname VARCHAR (100) 
                       , address1    VARCHAR(100)
                       )
GO
```

**Bulk Insert**

```
BULK INSERT UploadFile_Staging
FROM  N'D:\File_Folder\Data.txt'
WITH (FIRSTROW = 2
     ,FIELDTERMINATOR = '|'
     ,ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
     )
GO
```

Once you have data in sql server table use the following update statement to get rid of the text qualifiers double quotes and the escape characters.

**Data Tidy Query**

```
UPDATE  UploadFile_Staging
SET companyname = REPLACE(LEFT(STUFF(companyname,1,1,'') , LEN(companyname)- 2) , '\"', '"')
    ,address1    = REPLACE(LEFT(STUFF(address1,1,1,'') , LEN(address1)- 2) , '\"', '"')
```

**Result Set**

```
╔═══════════╦═════════════╦══════════════╗
║ accountno ║ companyname ║   address1   ║
╠═══════════╬═════════════╬══════════════╣
║      1234 ║ Toys "R" Us ║ 123 Main St. ║
╚═══════════╩═════════════╩══════════════╝
```

Answer (score 0):

`BULK INSERT` can be fussy with field quoting, separators appearing in quoted data etc etc. An alternative to mucking about with a [format file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms178129.aspx)  is it run the file through a bit of powershell to clean it up before `BULK INSERT`ing it as per @M.Ali's answer. This is just a personal preference of course, there's more than one way to do it.

For example:

```
Import-Csv  -Delimiter '|' -Path  $dirtyCsv |    #Change the delimiter to suit
  ConvertTo-CSV  -NoType -Delimiter '|' |        #Pipe delims help with commas in quoted text strings
  %{ $_.Replace('"','') } |                      #Add other cleanup here
  Out-File $cleanCsv                             #Et Volia, one clean file
```

A longer (self promo alert...) blog post on importing dirty csv files: https://www.rednotebluenote.com/2015/12/public-holiday-csv-wrangling/